# Como fazer scroll horizontal no tumblr

Tags: html, css, rolamento, horizontal

Olá!
Acho que o título diz tudo. Já tentei muitos tutoriais, mas não consigo nada.
O tema de base que estou a tentar alterar é o [seguinte](http://pastebin.com/b80miuhb).
Obrigada

Answer (score 0):

```
body {
overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

isso?

Comment: já tinha tentado e não resultou...

Answer (score -1):

```
body {
overflow-y:hidden;
overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

Comment: Não faz nenhuma diferença... há alguma alternativa? se quiser veja o tema que estou a usar (pus na pergunta em cima)